# Changes to primary key set on multiple fields in already existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012 enterprise version..

I have got table structure like below.. I need to remove the primary key and need to add primary key to the first column it self

and the table structure is given below ..

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivationInfo](
    [cert_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActivationKey] [varchar](1800) NULL,
    [Activated_ts] [datetime] NULL,
    [Activated_by] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FLAGGED] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

how can i remove the primary key that is already set on multiple fields after that i need to put primary key only for cert_id

would any one please help on this..

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple.  Duplicate of [Change Primary Key to Composite Key (Primary Key already exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167689/change-primary-key-to-composite-key-primary-key-already-exists?rq=1), just reverse the objective wanted.

```
ALTER TABLE ActivationInfo 
DROP CONSTRAINT CompositeKeyNameGoesHere, 

ALTER TABLE ActivationInfo 
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_CertID PRIMARY KEY (cert_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply achieved by dropping the Primary Key constraint and then adding a new one.

First you need to identify the name of your primary key constraint using the following code:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ActivationInfo' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Then you simply drop and replace the key:

```
ALTER TABLE ActivationInfo DROP CONSTRAINT **EXISTING NAME**
ALTER TABLE ActivationInfo ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ActivationInfo PRIMARY KEY (cert_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop use this construct: (IF u know the tablename)

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(100) = 'ActivationInfo'

SELECT 'alter table ' + @tablename
       + ' drop constraint ' + name
FROM   sys.objects
WHERE  type = 'pk'
       AND parent_object_id = Object_id(@tablename)
```

To Add Primary Key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ActivationInfo] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ActivationInfo_cert_id PRIMARY KEY(cert_id)
```